# Unable to connect interactively to container when using entrypoint script in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, shell, dockerfile

I need to initialize environment variables when running a container by the [script](https://gist.github.com/ahmetanbar/10257fd888323bf3bd3e4c6e99fcec37).

So write a shell script to initialize it when running a container by assign it to entrypoint.

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# Load the script of environment variables
. /home/foo/setupvars.sh
echo "INITIALIZZEE"
printenv
exec "$@"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

WORKDIR /home/foo

COPY entrypoint.sh /home/foo/entrypoint.sh
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/home/foo/entrypoint.sh"]
COPY setupvars.sh /home/foo/setupvars.sh
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/home/foo/setupvars.sh"]


ENTRYPOINT ["/home/foo/entrypoint.sh"]
```

[setupvars.sh](https://gist.github.com/ahmetanbar/10257fd888323bf3bd3e4c6e99fcec37)

I build the image,
`docker build -t foo .`
and run a container like:
`docker run --rm -it foo bash`

When  run a container, environment variable script run, `echo` run, `printenv` run. But I can't get any interactive bash. `exec "$@"` commands can't get my `bash` command. When I write there manually `bash` like exec "bash", it works.. On the other hand, it can't.

My steps are same in the [best practices of docker](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#entrypoint).

What is my mistake?

Comment: Change the `entrypoint.sh` script to use `#!/bin/bash`? You shouldn't try to source a bash script in a non-bash script. Also, you can set the execute bit on the entrypoint script in your local folder, and ditch the `RUN` directive.

Comment: @wmorrell yes I change, as I said in question. I replace `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: Then you should update the question with the actual code you are running, not what you were trying to run before you made changes. And are you rebuilding the image before trying to run it again? Just changing the Dockerfile is not sufficient to update the image.

Comment: @wmrorrell I edit.  I build and run for each change.

Comment: I don't think that's the code you're running, because when I run that, I get a bash prompt inside the container. Post your actual code.

Comment: I also can't reproduce. Works for me.

Comment: @wmorrell did you try it with `setupvars.sh`.  I try it also. And it doesn't works. I create differente folder and I try, what I say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see, the arguments lose when run another script in `entrypoint.sh`

So before run it, assign the arguments to a variable.

```
#!/bin/bash

# to save arguments assign them a variable before running script below
COM=$@
# Load the script of environment variables
. /opt/intel/openvino/bin/setupvars.sh
# export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
# export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/:$PYTHONPATH
echo "INITIALIZZEE"
printenv

# Run the main container command
exec $COM
```